# Windows 7 stuck after wake up - have tried several things already

Tags: windows-7, freeze, sleep, hibernate, suspend

My new PC (Intel Core Quad Q8400 2.66GHz, 2GB RAM) came with Windows 7 Ultimate 32-bit. It will wake up with a wireless keyboard after hibernation or suspend but it gets stuck there. It doesn't seem to recognize the keyboard, wireless mouse or digital board (pen) after it wakes up, and the screen is a bit darker than normal - however I can see the clock running normally, so I believe the PC has not frozen.

I had to reboot manually every time it went to sleep and it open it in safe mode. Now I have disabled sleep mode, but I have to turn the computer on manually each time or leave it powered on forever.

I have tried:

- Updated NVIDIA GeForce 8400 graphics card driver
- Updated mouse and keyboard drivers (Genius LuxeMate 3000)
- Fixed energy power settings to hybrid sleep off
- Turned hibernation on
- Turned sleep to never
- Fixed awake with device manager (mouse - keyboard - pen board)
- Fixed BIOS S1/S3 enabled wake with keyboard

However nothing has changed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I use Win 7 Ultimate 64-bit. I got the same problem. My PC froze when I left it for about 30 minutes. I tried everything that is advised on internet. Everything failed. By luck, I tried to manually put my PC to sleep mode by clicking Start->Shutdown ->Sleep whenever I leave my PC for a long period of time. It works for me, so I just want to share. Hope it works for you too.